# Count columns count as a result of select query

Tags: sql, db2

How to count the number of columns as a result of Select Query.

What i want is

There is a table with 100 columns but i am selecting only 40-45 columns. I want to know the count of columns selected.

Using schema inforation i can get the count of all the columns but i want the column count for that select query.

Is it possible.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can get the same info for a query. IIRC, there is a setting to only retrieve scheme when executing a query.

Comment: You can do what you are looking for against a SQL Server database by examining the query plan. It is not easy and there isn't a way that you can do it directly inside SQL server using a query.

Comment: @DavidBrabant oh sorry forgot to mention.I am using DB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by David Brabant, this depends heavily on the RDBMS you're using.

Here's a solution for Oracle using DBMS_SQL:

```
declare
  c       number;
  d       number;
  col_cnt integer;
  rec_tab dbms_sql.desc_tab;
begin
  c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

  dbms_sql.parse(c,
                 'select 1 as pk, 2 as value from dual',
                 dbms_sql.native);

  d := dbms_sql.execute(c);

  dbms_sql.describe_columns(c,
                            col_cnt,
                            rec_tab);
  dbms_output.put_line(col_cnt);
end;
```